# Python Selenium - How to configure a client certificate file while initializing PhantomJS driver instance

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I need to use a certificate (.cer) to connect to a website. I use PhantomJS with Python. This is the connection code:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="Selenium/bin/phantomjs", 
service_args=['--ssl-client-certificate-file=certificate.cer'],
desired_capabilities=dcap)
```

However, the HTML returned is:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

and the URL is:

```
about:blank
```

But if I remove:

```
'--ssl-client-certificate-file=certificate.cer'
```

Then I get the correct URL and some HTML content (forbidden message because the certificate is missing).

Any idea what I can do to solve this issue?

**UPDATE 1**
Ghostdriver.log contains the following:

```
[INFO  - 2018-04-27T15:18:44.680Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 55768
[INFO  - 2018-04-27T15:18:44.960Z] Session [46addab0-4a2e-11e8-879b-bb8782c84ba6] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2018-04-27T15:18:44.960Z] Session [46addab0-4a2e-11e8-879b-bb8782c84ba6] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2018-04-27T15:18:44.960Z] Session [46addab0-4a2e-11e8-879b-bb8782c84ba6] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"mac-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"},"phantomjs.page.settings.javascriptEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2018-04-27T15:18:44.960Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 46addab0-4a2e-11e8-879b-bb8782c84ba6
[INFO  - 2018-04-27T15:19:26.438Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
```

**UPDATE 2** - using logging.getLogger()

```
2018-04-30 09:39:56,730 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - POST http://127.0.0.1:57672/wd/hub/session {"requiredCapabilities": {}, "desiredCapabilities": {"platform": "ANY", "browserName": "phantomjs", "version": "", "phantomjs.page.settings.javascriptEnabled": true, "javascriptEnabled": true}}
2018-04-30 09:39:56,745 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - Finished Request
2018-04-30 09:39:56,745 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - POST http://127.0.0.1:57672/wd/hub/session/0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c/url {"url": "https://idp.iamfas.belgium.be/fasui/login/commercialnoidservice", "sessionId": "0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c"}
2018-04-30 09:39:56,971 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - Finished Request
2018-04-30 09:39:56,971 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - GET http://127.0.0.1:57672/wd/hub/session/0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c/source {"sessionId": "0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c"}
2018-04-30 09:39:56,974 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - Finished Request
HTML FOUND:
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
2018-04-30 09:39:56,974 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - GET http://127.0.0.1:57672/wd/hub/session/0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c/url {"sessionId": "0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c"}
2018-04-30 09:39:56,980 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - Finished Request
URL: about:blank
2018-04-30 09:39:56,980 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - POST http://127.0.0.1:57672/wd/hub/session/0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c/element {"using": "id", "sessionId": "0f971930-4c52-11e8-8957-cd8a79dc644c", "value": "proceedButton"}
2018-04-30 09:39:57,278 - selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection - DEBUG - Finished Request
```

Comment: Update the question with the trace level logs of PhantomJSDriver

Comment: Just updated with the logs from Ghostdriver.log

Comment: I don't see any warnings/errors within the logs you have provided. Can you add the relevant trace/error logs?

Comment: How can I do that? I tried driver.get_log('browser') but it gives me an empty list

Comment: Configure the logs for _TRACE_ level and update the question with the generated logs.

Comment: Just added logs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a certificate `(.cer)` while connecting to a website through *PhantomJS* and Python you need to provide the absolute path of the **--ssl-client-certificate-file** e.g. **C:\path\to\certificate.cer** as a `service_args`and you can use the following line of code :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="Selenium/bin/phantomjs", service_args=['--ssl-client-certificate-file=C:\path\to\certificate.cer'], desired_capabilities=dcap)
```

Comment: Thank you Debanjan! I now get some HTML returned. I decided to try with a .PFX file too. I figured I needed to use openssl to get .cer and .key files. I use: '--ssl-client-certificate-file' for the .cer, '--ssl-client-key-file' for the .key, and '--ssl-client-key-passphrase' for the PFX certificate password. Unfortunately, it seems that the website doesn't detect the certificate with PhantomJS (I tried with Chrome by entering manually, and the certificate is valid). Do you have any idea? thanks for your help

Comment: @eagle28 I am afraid, can't comment if _website doesn't detect the certificate with PhantomJS_. A detailed observation of the _HTML DOM_ of the _AUT_ might throw some light what's wrong happening. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will e happy to help you out.

Comment: Hi @eagle28 I had the similar problem. I extracted .cer and .key and used them the same way as you did with passphrase. Do you know how to solve that? Thanks

Comment: @YueLiu Let's discuss in details within [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)